# Internal Server Error 500 in deploying new app to Heroku

Tags: web, heroku, web-deployment, vs-web-site-project

I have finished the steps to deploy my website to Heroku, but when trying the URL, it gives me "Internal Server Error".

This is a small snippet from the Heroku Logs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmU0M.png)

I am also having 2 errors in the console:
GET https://thebiggame.herokuapp.com/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

Refused to load the image 'https://thebiggame.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.